# Why I need to enable Cloud NAT when downloading any patch for my OS even if I am using Private Google Access

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-vpc

I have enabled Private Google Access for my VPC. I enabled access for private.googleapis.com ( [used link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#console_2). But while running any OS upgrade like Windows Update or Linux Update (`sudo apt-get update`) I'm not able to connect the repositories. It worked after I enable Cloud NAT. Not sure why?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the documentation [Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-google-access):

> VM instances that only have internal IP addresses (no external IP
> addresses) can use Private Google Access. They can reach the external
> IP addresses of Google APIs and services.

and

> Private Google Access has no effect on instances that have external IP
> addresses. Instances with external IP addresses can access the
> internet, according to the [internet access requirements](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#internet_access_reqs).

also, at the documentation page [Cloud NAT overview](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview):

> Cloud NAT provides outgoing connectivity for the following resources:
>
> - Compute Engine virtual machine (VM) instances without external IP addresses

As a result, **Private Google Access provides your VMs access ONLY to [Google APIs and services](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-google-access#pga-supported)**, but to reach resources in the Internet ("like Windows Update or Linux Update") Cloud NAT is required.